# How to minify .aspx file by WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to minify .aspx file by WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms.

https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/WebMarkupMin:-ASP.NET-4.X-Web-Forms

I found a sample minification code in the above site.

```
namespace WebMarkupMin.Example.WebForms
{
   using System;
   using WebMarkupMin.WebForms.Pages;
   public partial class Contact : MinifiedAndCompressedHtmlPage
   {
      …
   }
}
```

So, I want to try it.
But, my class WebForm1 already has a base class System.Web.UI.Page, so I can not add MinifiedAndCompressedHtmlPage.

```
   public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      ...
   }
```

If you know the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `System.Web.UI.Page` class by `WebMarkupMin.WebForms.Pages.MinifiedAndCompressedHtmlPage` class:

```
using WebMarkupMin.WebForms.Pages;

public partial class WebForm1 : MinifiedAndCompressedHtmlPage
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: In our project we are using `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` as the base page (because we have webforms running legacy code inside of MVC) which inherits from `Page, IViewDataContainer`. Is there a practical way to override the inheritance upstream from `MinifiedAndCompressedHtmlPage, MinifiedAndCompressedPageBase, CompressedPage, UI.Page`?

Comment: @petrosmm, do these pages interact with controllers?

Comment: If these `.aspx`-files are in the `Views` directory, then they are not much different from `.cshtml`-files and you can apply action filters to the result of their output (via the action method, controller or `FilterConfig.cs` file). Just install the [WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc/) package and use the `MinifyHtmlAttribute` action filter. See the [“WebMarkupMin: ASP.NET 4.X MVC”](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/WebMarkupMin:-ASP.NET-4.X-MVC) section of documentation for details.

Comment: These pages are in a separate folder called legacy and they interact with code-behind not controllers so yes they have code on them... but they do not interact directly with MVC.

Comment: Maybe instead of the WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc and WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms modules you should use more universal solution - [WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/WebMarkupMin:-ASP.NET-4.X-HTTP-modules).

Comment: As soon as i configure the web.config in that directory, it will immediately compress incoming .aspx requests?

Comment: No, HTTP modules are not applied in sub directories - they can only be configured at the application level.

Comment: If you use a WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules module in a web application, then you can no longer use the WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc and WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms modules.

Comment: If you do not work with the `ViewBag` and `Model` objects in your `.aspx`-page code, then you can easily inherit your pages from the `MinifiedAndCompressedHtmlPage` or another similar class.

You can also take the [source code of WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms module](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/tree/master/src/WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms) and modify it for yourself. Don't forget to install a dependency of the WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.WebForms module - [WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Common/) package.